# ASP.NET Web API to issue cookie for SPA on different domain

Tags: angularjs, cookies, asp.net-web-api, oauth

My AngularJS SPA and its ASP.NET WebAPI 2 API are located on different domains. SPA user is authorized in API by obtaining JWT token from API auth server and then SPA sends each request with Authorization Bearer request header containing this token to access protected API endpoints.

Now we need to expose some API endpoints to be directly accessible by users when they are logged in to SPA. But I'm not sure how to implement it because we don't use cookies and our API is located on different domain than our SPA.

Is it possible to configure ASP.NET WebAPI 2 to issue cookie to a different domain (API domain) when POST request with credentials is sent from SPA from another domain?

Answer (score 0):

Consider that a cookie is being stored in client-side not in your server-side. You can add some tracker (i.e Google Analytics, or create your own tracker) to store the log data from users based on their tokens or their server variables like IP address, session key and so on.

Notice that tracker service will be launched on server-side and the tracker on the client-side like trackers JavaScript snippet-codes.